# Changing the font size of a text field in applet

Tags: java, user-interface, fonts, applet, awt

Is there any way to increase the font size of an applet?

```
TextField txtSentence = new TextField(60);
```

I need to increase the font size of txtSentence. Can somebody help please...
Thanx in advance........

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An AWT [`TextField`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TextField.html) inherits from `Component` which has the method [`Component.setFont(Font)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#setFont%28java.awt.Font%29).

### Tips

- AWT was the GUI component toolkit of last millennium.  This millennium, use Swing.
- Get used to looking in the JavaDocs for the class, as well as any class it implements or extends.  Many answers are to be found there.